# Crawlab - stablish a connection with Git repo

Tags: python, ssh, webhooks

I am trying to stablish a connection between Crawlab and my Github repo.

I did the following steps:

1. included the ssh-rsa key to my Git
2. added the webhook in github (maybe this step is not required)
   when I try to stablish a connection, I get an error, just as in image below:

[image]

The error message is:

> Request Error 500: http://:8080/api/git/branches?url=git@github.com:cfpf23%2Fdda_scraper.git&username=my_username&password=some_password. unable to find any valid known_hosts file, set SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS env variable

I tried to find documentation to access this error and I could not find anything. Hopefully I can get something by reaching out to the community

Comment: Just in case, did you also tried to `ssh-add <your-key>` from the host where crawlab is?

Comment: did you deploy crawlab with or without docker?